# React - Rechart - How to fill bottom part of Area in Composed Chart (Rechart.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, recharts

Here is the code that I tried:

```
            <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={500}>
                <ComposedChart
                    // width={500}
                    // height={400}
                    data={data}
                    margin={{
                        top: 20,
                        right: 20,
                        bottom: 20,
                        left: 20,
                    }}>
                    <CartesianGrid stroke="#f5f5f5" />
                    <XAxis axisLine={false} tickLine={false} dataKey="name" />
                    <YAxis
                        tick={{fill: '#4a4a4a', fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}
                        type="number"
                        domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']}
                        yAxisId="left"
                        tickLine={false}
                        axisLine={false}
                    />
                    <YAxis
                        tick={{fill: '#4a4a4a'}}
                        unit="x"
                        type="number"
                        domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']}
                        yAxisId="right"
                        orientation="right"
                        tickCount={10}
                        tickLine={false}
                        axisLine={false}
                    />
                    <Tooltip />
                    <Legend verticalAlign="top" align="right" height={40} />
                    <Area yAxisId="left" type="linear" dataKey="amt" fill="#8884d8" stroke="#8884d8" />
                    <Area yAxisId="left" type="linear" dataKey="pv" fill="#413ea0" stroke="#413ea0" />
                    <Line yAxisId="right" dot={false} type="linear" dataKey="uv" stroke="#ff7300" />
                    {/* <Scatter dataKey="cnt" fill="red" /> */}
                </ComposedChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
```

[Here is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWqcu.png)

Question is how to fill bottom part of a chart? 
It should fill everything under 0 on y-axis. 
Area should go all the way to the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When drawing an area in a graph, you need a reference. There is no way for anyone to know where your graph will end, and therefore where the filling should stop. Moreover, if you get rid of the 0 axis reference, you're getting rid of the meaning of an area chart aswell.

Your example is currently working as intended (from the docs with a tweak to adapt to your situation : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hvz98es/)).
I do not know if there is a way to do what you're looking for (and honestly can't find a good reason why). If I'm missing something and you absolutely want to do this I guess you could probably use fake data as a straight line at MIN_VALUE of your data and print it as an `Area` chart as well... It should look somewhat like this :
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hvz98es/1/)

But it doesn't make sense to me. Plus you'll have to figure out how to remove it from the Legend.

Comment: Ok, do you have a suggestion on how to fill the area under the line, on <Line /> element?
I use <Area /> because it has the ability to fill the area under line but it won't work well when my domain goes under 0

Comment: @Mare The second JSFiddle seems to be doing exactly that. From what I understand, ```Area``` fills the space left between your values and the 0 reference value on YAxis. Therefore, if you still want the area under 0 to be filled, you can use another ```Area``` component, with values drawing being the minimum value of your dataset (so it sticks to the bottom of the graph, without actually being seen), and fill it with the same color as the area you want filled under 0.

Comment: I managed to fix it, with range data that will have values 
[
  {
    value1, globalMinimum
  },
  {
    value2, globalMinimum
  }
]
and after that, I added custom tooltip where I ignore global minimum.
@Ragnar, thanks for the advice